# Group By MySQL Query that returns specific results with parameters

Tags: mysql

Before a user starts a private chat (between 2 members, not a group chat) I want to check and see if there is already a chat consisting of only these two members. In case they've deleted the chat on their end, when they go to message that same user again I want it to merge with the old chat instead of starting a duplicate chat for the same two members.

This is my structure

```
`chats` table
id     created_time 
 1     [TIMESTAMP]
 2     [TIMESTAMP]

`chats.parties` table   
id     chat_id     member_id     invited_by
 1     1           1             0 // creator of chat
 2     1           2             1
 3     1           3             1
 4     2           1             0
 5     2           2             1
```

Group by `chat_id` but only return results that contain a row with `member_id=1` and `member_id=2`; no more, no less.

In the case of the tables above, only the `chat_id=2` row(s) would be returned because `chat_id=1` contains a 3rd member.

Is this possible with raw SQL? I'd prefer to not loop through in php as it would take a while with a lot of chats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two different ways to get the result you are looking for:

```
-- using conditional aggregation
select chat_id from chat_parties
group by chat_id
having sum(case when member_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when member_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when member_id not in (1, 2) then 1 else 0 end) = 0

-- using a correlated subquery
select chat_id from chat_parties c1
where member_id in (1,2)
and not exists (
  select 1 from chat_parties where chat_id = c1.chat_id and member_id not in (1,2)
)
group by chat_id having count(distinct member_id) = 2
```

Change the table names to fit your actual setup.

Comment: Dont know why I tought need a left join for new created chat. But probably can remove that.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Indeed, as all the information that is asked for happened to be in one table only, but that isn't always the case so the left join is often needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional `COUNT`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/002df/3)**

```
SELECT c.`id`
FROM chats c
LEFT JOIN chats_parties cp
       ON c.`id`= cp.`chat_id`
GROUP BY c.`id`
HAVING COUNT(case when `member_id` = 1 then 1 END) >= 1 
   AND COUNT(case when `member_id` = 2 then 1 END) >= 1 
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT `member_id` ) = 2
```